# PHPUnit + symfony2: Excesive logging

Tags: php, symfony, ant, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit to run Unit tests and Functional Tests on a Web app developed with symfony.

Everytime I run the PHP Functional tests, I get an insane amount of logging messages, of this form:

```
 [exec] [2013-11-22 12:42:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\TestSessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"uid":"58329be"}
 [exec] [2013-11-22 12:42:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"uid":"58329be"}
 [exec] [2013-11-22 12:42:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"uid":"58329be"}
 [exec] [2013-11-22 12:42:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"uid":"58329be"}
```

...and some other stack traces, even though the tests pass.

This  is the target in my Ant Build Script:

```
<macrodef name="RunPHPUnitSuite">
    <attribute name="suite" />
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="php" failOnError="true" dir="${base.dir}">

        <arg value="C:\someDir\phpunit.phar" />

        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg value="symfony2\app" />

        <arg value="--testsuite" />
        <arg value="@{suite}" />

    </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="PHPUnitTests" depends="delete_test_reports">
    <RunPHPUnitSuite suite="UnitTests" />

    <replace file="${testReports.dir}\phpunit.xml" 
        token='testsuite name="UnitTests"' 
        value='testsuite name="PHP"' />

    <replaceregexp file="${testReports.dir}\phpunit.xml"
        match='testsuite name="(\w+\\)+'
        replace='testsuite name="'
        byline="true" />

    <replaceregexp file="${testReports.dir}\phpunit.xml"
        match='class="(\w+\\)+'
        replace='classname="PHPUnitTests.'
        byline="true" />

    <move file="${testReports.dir}\phpunit.xml" 
        tofile="${teamcityReports.dir}\php_unit_tests.xml" />
</target>
```

How could I cut down the level of messaging? The optimum output would be the one I get with the PHP Unit testing

```
 WebApp.PHPUnitTests:
      [exec] PHPUnit 3.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann.
      [exec]
      [exec] Configuration read from C:\Work\Software\WebApp\symfony2\app\phpunit.xml.dist
      [exec]
      [exec] ...............................................................  63 / 148 ( 42%)
      [exec] ............................................................... 126 / 148 ( 85%)
      [exec] ......................
      [exec]
      [exec] Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 12.00Mb
      [exec]
      [exec] ←[30;42m←[2KOK (148 tests, 266 assertions)
      [exec] ←[0m←[2K
      [move] Moving 1 file to C:\Work\Software\TestReports\

 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 Total time: 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Raising the action level of your logging in config.yml to 'error' or 'critical' would reduce the amount of logging, however for development they may be useful.

Comment: I dont have anything about Monolog in my config.yml... Im not sure what you mean